# Replace images in a DIV using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to show different images in a DIV, the turn of an image depend on a random number.
The image name is like 1.gif, 2.gif, .. 6.gif

to do that I coded

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "images/1.gif";
document.getElementById('imgDiv').appendChild(img);
```

but it does not replace the old image how ever it add an another image right in the bottom of first image.

syntax for DIV is:

```
<div id="imgDiv" style="width:85px; height:100px; margin:0px 10px 10px 375px;"></div>
```

may u halp me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
img.src = "images/1.gif";
var oldImg = document.getElementById('oldImg');
document.getElementById('imgDiv').replaceChild(img, oldImg);
```

Comment: exactly same posted by me... u posted first so i m deleting mine :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
var dv = document.getElementById('imgDiv');

// remove all child nodes
while (dv.hasChildNodes()) { 
    dv.removeChild(dv.lastChild); 
} 

var img = document.createElement("IMG"); 
img.src = "images/hangman_0.gif"; 
dv.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Great buddy,
it work perfects.
Please may u solve my old one problem described in my Question:Display label character by character using javascript?
I will be thankful to you..

Comment: This will work (as long as the div has no other children that you don't want deleted), but on some machines you'll see a flicker as the old image is removed and the new one added that won't occur if you use .replace instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace an element, you need to use [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild), not appendChild.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend changing the src of the element in question. That would cause a lag in the display of the next image while the browser downloads the next image. If you have a set number of images you would want to preload them the way you are doing so now.

If you have the following code:

```
 <div id="imgDiv" style="width:85px; height:100px; margin:0px 10px 10px 375px;"></div>
```

You can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
     var nextImage = document.createElement("img");
     nextImage.src = "your source here";

     document.getElementById("imgDiv").appendChild(nextImage);
</script>
```

Now that you have an image in place you can use the replaceChild() method:

```
var imageDiv = document.getElementById("imgDiv");
imageDiv.replaceChild(nextImage, imageDiv.childNodes[0]);
```